# Hypotheses for Sum of squares of degrees of irreducible representations equals order of group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions, cyclic-groups

Consider the group $G=C_n = \langle r|r^n \rangle$ (i.e. the cyclic group of order $n$). If $G$ acts on a complex vector space, then we know that $r$ acts on $v\in V$ by multiplication by an $n$ root of unity (including 1). Furthermore, these correspond to degree 1 characters. We see this from the fact that the sum of squares of degrees of irreducible representations equals order of group (referred to below as "sum of squares formula"; see for instance, Serre, *Linear Representation of Finite Groups*, p.18 Corollary 2 a. or [The Group Properties Wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_of_degrees_of_irreducible_representations_equals_order_of_group)).

Then I asked what happens when $G$ acts on $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ which we can identify with $\mathbb{C}$ via the usual vector space isomorphism. In this case, there are two kinds of invariant subspaces. If $r$ acts trivially, then $\text{span}_{\mathbb{R}}((1,0))$ is a 1-dimensional invariant subspace. However, if $r$ acts by rotation, say by rotation by $120^{\circ}$ (i.e. in the case $n=3$), then our subrepresentation is 2-dimensional because $r.(1,0) = \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$.

The sum of squares formula seems to fail in this real case because $\mathbb{R}$ is not a splitting field of $G$ (in the sense defined in The [Group Properties Wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_of_degrees_of_irreducible_representations_equals_order_of_group)).

Is there an analogue to the sum of squares formula in the real case?

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.